# Checking if a record exist returns "Sequence contains more than one matching element." for Net5 with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I have an .Net5 solution using Entity Framework 5.0.0. Im able to save data to the Backend SQL DB and all is well. But when I try to check is a record exist using the statement below im getting an error "***Sequence contains more than one matching element.***"

```
 var status = await dbContext.Item.AnyAsync(x => x.Name == "Bread")
```

I’m not sure what’s causing this. Any help appreciated

Im using the following packages

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0">
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0">
```

Comment: That's the error you get back from `Enumerable.Single()` (or equivalent) so that's quite strange.

Comment: The result must  have returned more than one element,Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Check your Model classes whether any of the properties has same name with different casing

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error that should come back from `AnyAsync`. I suspect there is something in the structure of your items (e.g. via a foreign key) that is generating the error. Use `ToTraceString()` to find out the underlying SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating all my EntityFramework related packages to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.17" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.17">
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.17">
```